# Magento 2: How to Display entered email address in notification message?

Tags: magento2.2, email, registration, notification

When i register the customer registration form if already customer are registere with the same email then i get message

**There is already an account with this email address. If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account.**

but i want to display email which the customer used in registration i want display as below: There is already an account with this email address **(display email address)**.

If you are sure that it is your email address, click here to get your password and access your account.how can i do that?

Comment: If you know please give answe@sumit

Comment: @savan patel if you know please give the answer

Comment: Any one know how can i do that?

Comment: @prashant valanda if you know please help me